# Internet Explorer and the disappearing XMLHttpRequest nodelist

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have a loadXML() function that works in IE on the first time around. The XML data is stored as a nodelist into a global variable that is used to first populate a table. It is later validated against user input. The table populates, but later when the user clicks a button to cause the validation, the global variable is mysteriously empty.

I understand this is probably due to the asynchronous nature of XMLHttpRequest. How can I store the nodelist into a permanent global variable?

```
function loadXml(ws)
{
    xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {

        if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200)
        {
            xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            xmlAns = "";
            x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("question");
            populate();
        }
    }
    xml.open("GET", "xml/" + ws + ".xml", true);
    xml.send();
}
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: Version 6-9 don't work. Version 10 does. All other browsers work.

Comment: Your global is called `x`?  There might be some other (3rd party?) code being loaded that also uses global `x`.  Trying changing the global var name to something less common?

Comment: There is no other script calls to 3rd party code. Just the one.